# google analytics api - events and all sessions

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am trying to retrieve all sessions and all events in a single query. However, the query below will only return sessions if they also have events. Is there a way to get all sessions even if they don't have events.

```
GaData gaResults = analytics.data().ga().get("ga:" + profileId, processDate, processDate, "ga:sessions,ga:bounces")
                .setDimensions("ga:date,ga:source,ga:medium,ga:campaign,ga:eventCategory,ga:eventAction,ga:eventLabel")
                .setSort("-ga:date")
                .setMaxResults(5000)
                .setStartIndex(start_index)
                .execute();
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking for is not possible with the way the [Core Reporting API v3](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/) works.

When you ask the API for a dimension, it won't return any rows if it doesn't have a value for that dimension. Sometime the API will return the value "(not set)", but this is only for dimensions where it makes sense to do, e.g. `ga:browser` or `ga:city` where clearly a value could apply but the value may not be known. For other dimensions it wouldn't make sense to do that, e.g. `ga:socialAction` since obviously not every hit contains a social action.

I'm curious to know what you even expect the results to look like for the request you're making? What would the event category, action, and label be for a session if that session didn't contain any event hits?